# Are inherited object and base object stored in 2 memory space/block?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have class BaseObject and InheritedObject inherites from BaseObject.

In BaseObject, I have field "public int Id".
In InheritedObject, I have field "public new long Id".

**Question**:
When new instance of InheritedObject is created, are inherited object and base object stored in 2 memory space/block?

For more specific, I have address 0x001 to store the BaseObject and address 0x100 to store the InheritedObject .
And InheritedObject has reference to BaseObject using address 0x001.

Comment: If you're asking whether the object and its subobjects are stored together, then yes - an object has all inherited subobjects stored within itself. They don't hold pointers or references to each other. If you're asking something else you'll need to clarify further.

Comment: @molbdnilo: my concern is do we have 2 memory spaces for each object? They can be next to each other, or the InheritedObject includes the BaseObject memory space?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming c#, Yes two discrete fields are created. So two memory space will be allocated.

When you add `new` modifier, you shadow the base class's field. So when you access the field with derived type you'll get the value from `InheritedObject` and to get the value of `BaseObject.Id` you can access it via base object type.

Note: You can change the data type also when shadowing in derived class, so it is obvious that separate memory location is used.

Comment: If I dont use new modifier (e.g. I use override modifier), do I have 2 memory space for 2 Ids? My concern is do we have 2 memory spaces for each object? They can be next to each other, or the InheritedObject includes the BaseObject memory space?

Comment: @VuNguyen You can't use override modifier for field.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if I use properties, like this public override int Id {get; set; }

Comment: @VuNguyen Yes, if you use like that base class will have a separate backing field and derived class will also have a separate backing field. Hence two memory locations will be allocated.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help. I have an argument with my friend and he don't know this, he insist that if I do overriding or hiding, no matter what, there is only one memory space, but I don't know how to show him. Do you have any official documentation somewhere?

Comment: Download IL Spy, or reflector and check the decompiled compiled code? If not [this should answer your friend's question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417463/are-anonymous-backing-fields-still-created-for-virtual-auto-implemented-properti)